# What is the difference between 'prendere in braccio' and 'prendere un braccio'?

Tags: word-meaning, difference, english-comparison, sentences

What is the difference between *prendere in braccio* and *prendere un braccio* ?

Here's the context where I encountered the both expressions. It is from a campaign against child violence:

> Ogni giorno il mio papà torna a casa, mi prende <s>un</s> in braccio, mi dà un ba<s>cal</s>cio e mi dice che sono stup<s>ido</s>endo.

I understand *prendere in braccio*, but what does the other expression mean in this situation. Sorry for not including the above passage in the original version of the question, but I wasn't aware that it is so problematic.

Comment: What do you mean by "prendere un braccio"?

Comment: where do you get [these](http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1704/what-is-the-best-english-traslation-of-dai-che-ce-dai) from?

Comment: *Prendere un braccio* can be used only in very special situations; maybe *prendere per un braccio* would be more common. The phrase *prendere in braccio* means *to take someone in one's arms*, *to hold*.

Comment: I edited the question to give the context. @WalterTross I will also edit the other question to explain how I encountered the expression.

Comment: great campaign, it's a pity that it will be hard to translate the pun. Only "ki[ck]sses me" come to my mind

Comment: "stup[id]endous" is not that bad either.

Comment: I would like to read your full translation of this sentence, once you have it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this context, "prendere [un bambino] **in** braccio" means "to hold [a child] in someone's arms" (as in egreg's comment); "prendere **un** braccio" means "to grab an arm", implying that the gesture is violent.

Comment: ... but if you are employed in a doll's factory it is a very common sentence without violence implications

Comment: actually "hold in one's arms" is "tenere in braccio", rather than "prendere in braccio"

Comment: @WalterTross True, of course, in this case the sense of the sentence doesn't change much though. You can also say "pick up [a child] into one's arms".